# Search in a consensus sequence with ambiguous bases

Tags: biopython

I have a consensus sequence with ambiguous bases, in which I want to search for a pattern. Start position should be 3.

```
Seq="ATGARTTTTTT" -- R is A or G
Pattern="AGT"
```

I found a tool called nt_search in SeqUtils that can do that but it doesn't give me the coordinates of the match as illustrated in scenario #2. Below are a few test runs to demonstrate the issue.

Scenario #1: No Ambiguous Bases

```
from Bio import SeqUtils
pattern="TAA"
Seq="ATGTAAAGGAGG"
m=SeqUtils.nt_search(Seq,pattern)
print m
['ACG', 3]
```

Scenario #2: Ambiguous Bases in sequence

```
pattern="AGT"
Seq="ATGARTTTTTT"
m=SeqUtils.nt_search(Seq,pattern)
print m
['AGT']
```

Scenario #3: Ambiguous Bases in pattern

```
pattern="ART"
Seq="ATGAGTTTTTT"
m=SeqUtils.nt_search(Seq,pattern)
print m
['A[AG]T', 3]
```

The source code for nt_search is [here](ftp://biomoby.org/pub/biopython/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils-pysrc.html). I am not sure how to tweak it to get the start position, in this example, that would be 3.

Answer (score 1):

The help text for `nt_search` could be much clearer, but it returns a list giving the regular expression used and the position of any matches. e.g.

```
>>> from Bio.SeqUtils import nt_search
>>> print(nt_search("ATGAGTTTTTT", "ART"))
['A[AG]T', 3]
>>> print(nt_search("ATGAGTTTTTTAGT", "ART"))
['A[AG]T', 3, 11]
>>> print(nt_search("ATGAGTTTTTTAGTTTTAAT", "ART"))
['A[AG]T', 3, 11, 17]
```

So, if you want the first match only as an integer, you need to pull out element one from the list:

```
>>> from Bio.SeqUtils import nt_search
>>> print(nt_search("ATGAGTTTTTTAGT", "ART")[0])
A[AG]T
>>> print(nt_search("ATGAGTTTTTTAGT", "ART")[1])
3
```

Element zero would be the regular expression used.

Update: Searching against an ambiguous sequence is not (currently) supported (scenario 2 in the question), in part I would think as it would be difficult to define a sensible implementation. e.g. searching as against `"NNN"`with any any three letter query like `"AAA"`, `"ART"`, or `"NNN"` would give you a match.

Comment: Many thanks Peter for your reply. In that scenario, it works perfectly. But it doesn't work when the sequence we are searching in contains the ambiguous bases, regardless if the pattern we are searching for contains or doesn't contain ambiguous bases. It is illustrated in scenario #2 in my question. Thanks again :)

Comment: That is correct, the ``nt_search`` function does not (currently) support searching against an ambiguous sequence.

Comment: You should probably ask a more general question about how to do this in Biopython (or Python). Most likely Biopython's ``motifs`` module would be appropriate.

Comment: I will look into the motifs module then. Many thanks!